# ng-templates inline, but still tried to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ACZUqfjnunYhYMNhAiaO?p=preview),

```
<script type="ng/template" id="/my-template.html?id=123">
  Inline template. Yes!
</script>

app.directive('gameListing', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',      
    templateUrl: '/my-template.html?id=123'
};
```

but I cannot figure out why the h*ll Angular still tries to load the template, even though it's defined in the id-property of the script-tag.

Can anybody please help me out here? I would need to have this inline, not loading with (yet) another request.

Thanks!

Comment: Use <script type="text/ng-template" id="page.html" > </script>

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't that what I do? Apart from specifying the complete path (which is needed in my case, I promise :).

Comment: you are not including it in right manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html?id=123">
 Inline template. Yes!
</script>

 app.directive('gameListing', function() {
   return {
   restrict: 'EA',      
   templateUrl: 'my-template.html?id=123'
  };
```

Comment: Gosh... text/ng-template, how on earth did I come up with ng/template?!

Comment: Haha . it happens.!! Cross check before putting in SO (Y)

Answer (score 0):

as "/my-template.html?id=123" this path is relative to your root directive so it would try to find out in your root folder. please modify template id like - 
id="my-template.html?id=123"
and access it in same way templateUrl: 'my-template.html?id=123'